# Fix 'Cannot set properties of undefined' error in Typescipt when using Record

Tags: typescript

I have the following variable:

```
const sorting: Record<string, { filters: [], appliedFilters: [], search: string }> = {};
```

And I want to initialize it as following:

```
export let tableData: { props: (string | { name: string, ... })[] };

tableData.props.forEach((item) => {
    if(typeof item === 'string') {
    sorting[item].filters = [];
    sorting[item].appliedFilters = [];
    sorting[item].search = '';
    } else {
    sorting[item.name].filters = [];
    sorting[item.name].appliedFilters = [];
    sorting[item.name].search = '';
    }
});
```

But when I run the it I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'filters')

It might be worth noting that I am using Svelte and this code is ran inside a component where `tableData` is an atribute, although I don't think this would change anything

I have already tried setting the type of the variable to object and that doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can fix this without resorting to `any` type

Comment: You need to check if `sorting[item]`/`sorting[item.name]` has a value (by default it will be `undefined`) before trying to assign properties, if blank give it a default (e.g. `{}`)

Comment: Also doing something like `const key = typeof item === "string" ? item : item.name` and then indexing using `key` instead of `item` or `item.name` would save you a bit of duplication and make this code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with typescript. `sorting` is an empty object so `sorting[item]` or `sorting[item.name]` is always undefined.

You need to first define `sorting[item]` before defining the properties within it.

```
sorting[item] = {
    filters: [],
    appliedFilters: [],
    search: ''
};
```

The following would be a more accurate type description for the `sorting` object.

```
const sorting: Record<string, { filters: [], appliedFilters: [], search: string } | undefined> = {};
```